# Contact Form 7 fields list by form id?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

How can I get all "Contact Form 7" fields as object by a form id?

There is a function who do that?
Do I need to take the content of the post and handle it with the regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact Form 7 forms are just posts with a custom post type of `wpcf7_contact_form`. The form fields are saved as html (with shortcodes) as post meta with a key of `_form`. In order to get this data, you can use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Again...this won't actually return the rendered html fields...just the shortcodes and other form layout. The actual form fields aren't rendered until WPCF7 runs `do_shortcode()`.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to get Contact form 7 form fields:

```
$form_ID     = 1538; # change the 1538 to your CF7 form ID
$ContactForm = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance( $form_ID );
$form_fields = $ContactForm->scan_form_tags();
var_dump( $form_fields );
```

The below code will also work.

```
 $fieldsArray   = get_post_meta(1538);  # change the 1538 to your CF7 form ID
 $meta          = $fieldsArray['_form'][0];
 $TagsManager   = WPCF7_FormTagsManager::get_instance();
 $tags          = $TagsManager->scan( $meta );
 $form_fields   = $TagsManager->filter( $tags, $data );
 var_dump( $form_fields );
```

But it's not the Preferred way.